# Как изменить разрешение экрана Windows 7?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7

Как изменить разрешение экрана windows 7?
Желательно на языке с++. Или нужно visual c++? Если это большая тема, то хотя бы с чего начать. Библиотеку подгрузить возможно надо. Есть задача чтобы программа устанавливала одно разрешение, потом другое.

Comment: Вот аналогичный вопрос на английском https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215412/programmatically-change-screen-resolution . в ответе есть ссылки на документацию Microsoft